# Layered navigation showing error in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, layered-navigation, multiselect-attribute

I am using BSS layered nabigation extension.
After installing, i am getting one error.
See below:
I am using BSS layered navigation.
but it showing error and my site is not working.

```
Error:
{"0":"Class Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection\\SearchCriteriaResolverFactory does not exist\nClass Bss\\LayerNavigation\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection\\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin\/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only.","1":"<pre>#1 Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Generator\\Autoloader->load()\n#2 spl_autoload_call()\n#3 ReflectionClass->__construct() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Code\/Reader\/ClassReader.php:19]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Reader\\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Definition\/Runtime.php:49]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Definition\\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:48]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:56]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->create() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Product\/CollectionFactory.php:43]\n#8 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\CollectionFactory->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog-search\/Model\/Layer\/Category\/ItemCollectionProvider.php:36]\n#9 Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\Layer\\Category\\ItemCollectionProvider->getCollection() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Model\/Layer.php:146]\n#10 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Layer->getProductCollection() called at [generated\/code\/Bss\/LayerNavigation\/Model\/Layer\/Category\/Interceptor.php:50]\n#11 Bss\\LayerNavigation\\Model\\Layer\\Category\\Interceptor->getProductCollection() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct.php:459]\n#12 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct->initializeProductCollection() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct.php:116]\n#13 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct->_getProductCollection() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct.php:348]\n#14 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct->getIdentities() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct\/Interceptor.php:154]\n#15 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct\\Interceptor->getIdentities() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/Layout\/LayoutPlugin.php:71]\n#16 Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\Layout\\LayoutPlugin->afterGetOutput() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:146]\n#17 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#18 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php:494]\n#19 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Page.php:258]\n#20 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page->render() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Layout.php:171]\n#21 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Layout->renderResult() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#22 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#23 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#24 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Result\/Page\/Interceptor.php:130]\n#25 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:140]\n#26 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#27 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:258]\n#28 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap-
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command from the CLI :

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
chmod -R 777 var/ generated/
```

Comment: Hi Dhiren, I run all commands but still I am facing same issue.

Comment: check what is your permission of generated folder, or try run this command first : chmod -R 777 var/ generated/